# asp.net5 dbContext dependency injection for xUnit test

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, xunit, asp.net-core

Trying to get my services injected correctly into my unit tests. work fine in my controllers, Used the same method of passing in DbContext on the constructor.

```
 public class PostTest
{

    public BlogContext db { get; set; }

    public PostTest(BlogContext Context)
    {
        db = Context;
    }
```

All my subsequent tests fail due to :

The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: BlogContext Context

My OnConfigure setup is

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        // Adding CORS to api
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin());
        });

        string connstr = "Data Source=(localdb)\\ProjectsV12;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";


        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<BlogContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(connstr));

        //services.AddScoped<BlogContext>(provider => provider.GetService<BlogContext>());

    }
```

and this is an example of my blog controller - this works fine.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class BlogController : Controller
{

    private BlogContext db;

    public BlogController(BlogContext dbContext)
    {
        db = dbContext;

      //  db = new BlogContext();

    }

    //public BlogContext db;


    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    //public IEnumerable<Post> Get()
    public Post Get(int id)
    {
        try {
            Post FoundPost = db.Posts.Where(x => x.id == id).Single();
            return FoundPost;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new Post { id = 0 };
        }  
    }
```

Any advise would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this for unit testing or integration testing? Because NikolaiDante's answer (which is a very good answer) only aplies to unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it slightly differently in the test class:

```
 public class BlogControllerFacts
 {
        public class Index
        {
            [Fact]
            public void GetDoesSomething()
            {
                // Arrange
                BlogContext db = new BlogContext(); // This should be mocked somehow
                const int id = 5;
                var controller = new BlogController(db);

                // Act
                var result = controller.Get(id);

                // Assert something
            }

        }
    }
}
```